# What people can do if they know the name of my .php file?

Tags: php, jquery, file, security

I use jquery to load some files:

```
$("#mUm").load("drop_menu_loop.php");
```

In this file i have a `foreach` loop and `require_once 'database_config.php';`

This question might be stupid, but i'm kinda insecure, so i wanted to ask.

What kind of code should i not load with jquery?

Comment: It's hard to say since we don't know what the contents of the php files are. If there contains anything that could compromise a database and/or files, then we need to know what we're really dealing with here. The question in that respect is unclear for me.

Comment: This question is very misleading yourself. The real question should be which resources are available on my server from through the web. Always assume that people know exactly what files are in your public directory and can request your web server for any of them.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i did said the contents that are in my php file, a data base config example: `$username:.. $password:.., $hostname:..`, and a `select` query with `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to load whatever you'd like with JQuery as you will be loading in PHP scripts and those are all serverside. Now if someone were to get their hands on the locations of your PHP files, one thing they could do is potentially send POST requests to those pages modifying your database, however, many of these pages would already be exposed from your forms. You can prevent this by adding CSRF protection methods to your site.

Any directory within your root web directory is not private so it is important to add these protective measures anyways.

So overall, load whatever you'd like through JQuery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `potentially send POST requests to those pages modifying your database` could you give more infomation about this? Are you talking about sql injection?

Comment: @user236945896 So for many PHP websites that have forms, when those forms are submitted, the will send a request to a location. The location depends on the `action` attribute and the method depends on the `method` attribute. So let’s say we have `<form method="post" action="/login.php" />` when you click submit, `login.php` gets a post request where there is a script taking the data from that post request(`$_POST['data'];`) and using it to send a query to the database. Instead of going through your form, somebody could send a request from their own server. A way this can be malicious is spam.

Comment: I made a seach on google about CSRF and most of the articles that i found talks about a malicious link with `method GET` that a "authenticated" user (the victim) should click, example: `http://bank.co/transfer.do?acct=HACKER&amount=500`, i don't know how could CSRF affect my data base...

Comment: @user236945896 So the page `bank.co/transfer.do` would be accepting requests, in that case, GET and use the data in those requests to send off in the database. How that would affect your database would be that a query is sent to your database to add $500 to the hacker’s account. Sometimes what the hacker does can be more malicious, such as perform an SQL injection attack if you have no server side protections or they could even modify another user’s data without even being logged in.

Comment: I'm good about SQL Injection, i made safe queries with `prepared statement`, let's talk about this: `How that would affect your database would be that a query is sent to your database to add $500 to the hacker’s account` only it? so it's more like user's account security, right? So CSRF could not modify my database tables, right? If you think that CSRF cound modify my datable, could you give me a example of how would it works?

Comment: @user236945896 Yeah, sorry for the confusion. When I said modify database, what I meant like that is what you said, user account security and not modifying the actual tables. My bad.